# set initial state from javascript and state.json

Tags: react-native

I exported my application state from debugger: state.json

I would like to use it as initial state before execute my e2e tests.

Is it possible to import it from a javascript script ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do this is by adding a mock prop to all of my components and in the constructor I load the state with that info, but I am not sure this would work for you because all my components are stateless. All their behavior is based on props.

And yes, I know that there is a reason the state is there but I use High Order Components.